# reset rich:calendar value on jsf form using java script

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to reset value of rich:calender input box via java script but couldnt do it any way at all. the UI of my form (snippet only) is...

```
 <rich:calendar id="startDate" datePattern="dd MMM yyyy"                    value="#{classBean.startDate}" popup="true" onchanged="calcDuration();">
 </rich:calendar>
```

the java script is

```
    function calcDuration()
{
sdate =$('frm_course:startDate').component.getSelectedDateString("dd MMM 
   yyyy");
   var currentdate = new Date();
   var sdatecmp = new Date(sdate);          

   if(sdatecmp > currentdate)
{
 alert('The Start Date is Greater than today!');
$('frm_viewCourseDetail:startDate').component.value = ""; // 1
     document.getElementById('frm_course:startDate').value =""; // 2     
}
  }
```

None of the lines 1 and 2 resets the richcalender's value. Help is required here. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calendar (and other components) is backed by a JavaScript object which has the methods you need.

Use either `#{rich:component('startDate')}` or `RichFaces.$('startDate')` to get a reference to that object and then call `resetValue()`.

For other methods check the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-richcalendar-JavaScript_API)